# Configuration Profile with MDM Payload not getting installed

Tags: iphone, ios, payload, mdm

I am working on MDM stuff, trying to install Configuration Profile having MDM payload, but its not getting installed on the device.
I want to perform remote lock/wipe from MDM server.
Any help really appreciated.
Please help me to resolve this, here is Payload content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> <plist version="1.0"> <dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>AccessRights</key>
            <integer>2047</integer>
            <key>CheckInURL</key>
            <string>https://192.168.1.101:8080/xyz/profile</string>
            <key>IdentityCertificateUUID</key>
            <string>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</string>
            <key>PayloadDescription</key>
            <string>Configures MobileDeviceManagement.</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.xyz.mdm.mdm1</string>
            <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
            <string>Xyz</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.mdm</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>ServerURL</key>
            <string>https://192.168.1.101:8080/xyz/profile</string>
            <key>SignMessage</key>
            <false/>
            <key>Topic</key>
            <string>com.apple.mgmt.xyz</string>
            <key>UseDevelopmentAPNS</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>PayloadDescription</key>
    <string>MDM Profile</string>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>MDM</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.xyz.mdm</string>
    <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
    <string>Xyz</string>
    <key>PayloadRemovalDisallowed</key>
    <false/>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Configuration</string>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer> </dict> </plist>
```

Comment: Please provide the error message that is displaying on the iPhone, as well as any errors appearing in the device console during the install. You can view the device console by connecting your device to your computer and opening "iPhone Configuration Utility". I believe Xcode also has a library tool of sorts for this.

Answer (score 4):

Now a lot of help is available to implement MDM. If you are still facing the issue,use IPCU to generate the mobileconfig profile which you need to install in the iOS device.

Verify the below things also by referring these links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547520/mdm-ota-last-profile-in-idevice-enrollment/10577182#10577182), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293363/how-to-set-mdm-payloads-identity-in-ipcu/10577216#10577216) , [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571190/apns-notifications-not-reaching-devices-enrolled-in-apple-mdm/10629174#10629174) and [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545246/mdm-apns-notification-does-not-reach-iphone/10629281#10629281) .

- Please check the identity.p12 and password is correct one.
- The server url which you are using that should exist.
- The topic should be correct.
- The APNS certificate should be in required format.

Please refer [MDM_Protocol](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf) pdf document and [this_page](http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning) very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

are the required ports open on the server? Try apple configuration utility to create the configuration profile. Choose the certificate using the tool. It will error out if there are any obvious errors