# Unable to send MDM Push Notification to the device via APNS.

Tags: c#, mdm

Unable to send MDM Push Notification to the device via APNS.

We are in process of installing our own MDM server and there by controlling the devices enrolled.

Our MDM server is 64 bit Windows 2008 R2 server. We  have obtained the push certificate from the website https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/ using the mdm certificate created using our enterprise license.

We have also completed the enrollment of the device using the configuration profile. We could retrieve the pushmagic and UDID using the check in url provided in the configuration profile.

Now using that information we are trying to send push notificate to the apple sandbox server "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com". I have installed the push certificate received from the apple in the MDM server (by conveting the pem to p12).

We are using C#(MOONAPNS/PUSHSHARP) as program  to send the payload information to the APNS. The information which we are sending is something like {"mdm","C00B83E6-7B66-4DE3-BBE4-B728E0E3E16F"} along with the device token. This never gets to wake up the device. The c# program which connects to the APNS is not throwin any error and says successfully sent. But the APNS doenst seem to be waking up the ipad device( based on the logs in the ipad.)

I am completely stuck here and not sure how to proceed further. How to debug this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have the wrong certificate. You need a different switch flipped in your profile to become an MDM Vendor in order to have the correct certificate to administer devices like you are trying to. You cannot use the certificate you got with your enterprise account.

Answer (score 0):

For MDM you don't need to use the Sandbox URL you can use the Production URL itself.
Try using production environment through gateway.push.apple.com, port 2195.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10629281/8472539)